# Virtualbox to reach network devices with the same IP of the host

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, windows-server-2012

I have 1 host machine with Windows 2012 Server. This server has 1 IP address. This IP is the only one that can reach the network devices (routers and switches).

I must run a software that collects information via Telnet and SNMP. This software runs only on Windows 7.

I installed Virtualbox with Win7. The problem is that:

- If I set VB to bridged network, it will get a new address from the DHCP server. If I put the static IP address that has the host machine it will create a conflict.
- If I set it to NAT, VB will not have access to the devices... no ping, snmp, telnet to the routers
- If I set it to internal only... well... it's internal.

Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for, with Virtualbox and Windows 7? If yes, how should I configure it?

To summarize:
Windows 7 on the virtual machine should have access to the other devices in the network, and these devices should see that the queries are coming from the IP address of the Server (host machine).

Thanks

Comment: Setting the guest to use NAT should work. You should investigate why it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vritual Machine Network adapter to NAT connection should work for you. If there is no access to ping and telnet then the security software may block the connection. Please check your firewall and Antivirus softwares. To isolate the issue, disable your windows OS Firewall and Antivirus softwares temporarily and check the connectivity.

Hope this helps.